# How to do a query between date using jQuery SPServices CAMLQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I have some trouble retrieving items from a list where the program should retrieve the list of items with a certain range of dates provided by the user.

Here is my sample code:

```
function getItems(startDate, endDate){
    var query =
        "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
                "<And>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='Date'>" + > startDate + "</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='Date'>" + < startDate + "</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                "</And>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Start' Ascending='false' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>";

    $().SPServices......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took me time to figure it out but i finally did it.

```
function getItems(startDate, endDate){
    var query =
        "<Query>" +
            <Where>" +
                "<And>" +
                    "<Geq>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name=\"Start\" />" +
                         "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + fromdate + "</Value>" +
                    "</Geq>" +
                    "<Leq>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name=\"Start\" />" +
                         "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + todate + "</Value>" +
                    "</Leq>" +
                "</And>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Start' Ascending='false' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>";
   $().SPServices......
}
```